# Assign return value to a table field

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, ax

I need to insert a value to the field table and I have a display method which returns this value
Is there a way to assign a return value from display method to a table field or calling  this display method in insert()?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, you can use display methods just as you do ordinary methods. So, to add the value of a display method as a value to a table (in the insert or initValue method) just state:

```
this.[FieldName] = this.[MethodName]();
```

If you are on a different object (IE, not a table), it may need to be accessed differently, but the concept is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a best practice, you can use the return value of a display method like any other methods. This said, the best practice is to not do it that way but create a getXXX method that get the value, and a display method that returns the new get method return value:

```
private Qty getQty() // it can be public if it's needed
{
    Qty q;
    ;

    // do stuff to get or calculate the return value

    return q;
}

display Qty displayQty() // displays are always public by default
{
    return this.getQty();
}
```

This way you can assign appropiate security to the display method whithout interfere the logic to get the value, and the get method will be reusable for displaying but also for other methods.